# Deserialize Json - Object of objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have some JSON being sent to me that looks like this:

```
{"MessageCodes": {
      "Code1": "Message 1",
      "Code2": "Message 2",
      "Code3": "Message 3",
      "Code4": "Message 4",
      "Code5": "Message 5",
      "Code6": "Message 6",
}}
```

This is saying there is an object called `MessageCodes` which contains many other objects within it (`Code1`, `Code2`, etc...). The object names, `Code1`, `Code2`,... are just example object names. The JSON I am receiving contains hundreds of objects contained within the `MessaageCodes` object. All are name value pairs.

I am using JSON.net by Newtonsoft to deserialize the JSON sent to me. Does anyone know how I can deserialize the above JSON into a Dictionary?

Comment: What you've posted is not valid JSON, so it couldnt be parsed into a dictionary.  It appears that you need to specify your object (class) name, then `MessageCodes` would be a dictionary property on that class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net)

Comment: Oops, simple mistake with the improperly formatted JSON. Hopefully people can still understand the question being asked... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your JSON is not properly formatted.  If it represents an object, it should be wrapped in outer braces:

```
var json = @"{'MessageCodes': {
  'Code1': 'Message 1',
  'Code2': 'Message 2',
  'Code3': 'Message 3',
  'Code4': 'Message 4',
  'Code5': 'Message 5',
  'Code6': 'Message 6'}}";

var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(json);

public class Test
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> MessageCodes { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Newtonsoft.Json you can do next:

```
   var jsonString = @"{'MessageCodes': {'Code1': 'Message 1','Code2': 'Message 2','Code3': 'Message 3'}";
   var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonString)
                .GetValue("MessageCodes")
                .ToDictionary(x => x.First.Path, x => x.First.Value<string>());
```